# How to clean up resources if FtpWebRequest goes wrong

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I wonder if this FtpWebRequest goes wrong and, it goes to the catch event. I have seen an example code where they posted what I have uncommented in the catch event, - to clean up the resources.

But I don't know what is the proper way to do that in this scenario? Should I just put all of those to: = null; or is this wrong to do? What is the proper way to do it?

`cleanUp(sourceStream, ref response, ref requestStream, ref request);`

```
void uploadimage()
        {
            String sourceimage = "C:/ESD/image_2.jpg";
            Task<bool> task = FtpUploadFile(sourceimage);
            if (task.IsFaulted == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(task.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
        private Task closeRequestStreamAsync(Stream requestStream) { return Task.Run(() => { requestStream.Close(); }); }
        public async Task<bool> FtpUploadFile(string filename)
        {
            //if exception occurs we want to be able to close these
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            FtpWebRequest request = null;
            FileStream sourceStream = null;
            Stream requestStream = null;
            try
            {
                bool isimage = false; String ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".bmp") { isimage = true; }

                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someurl.com/Folder1/test1.jpg");
                request.UsePassive = true;
                if (isimage == true) { request.UseBinary = true; } //for images
                if (isimage == false) { request.UseBinary = false; } //for text
                request.KeepAlive = true; //keep the connection open
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.ConnectionGroupName = "Group1";
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 4;

                //These are the credentials.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");


                sourceStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[sourceStream.Length];
                await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                sourceStream.Close();

                requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                //MPM  This is the call that takes the time     
                await closeRequestStreamAsync(requestStream);

                //response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                WebResponse responseWeb = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                response = (FtpWebResponse)responseWeb;
                if (response.StatusDescription.Contains("226"))
                {
                    //This means that we successfully have uploaded the file!
                }
                response.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errMSG = string.Format("Upload File failed, exception: {0}", ex.Message);
        //cleanUp(sourceStream, ref response, ref requestStream, ref request);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: *Don't* declare variables at the start of the method. That's a very bad practice, giving them greater scope than they need, and making the code a lot harder to read. Declare the variables only when you need them, preferably assigning them their values during definition. As for  FtpWebRequest, declare the variable inside a `using` block, eg `using (var FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(..){ ....}`. This ensures the value will be disposed even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Don't just swallow exceptions either. Either handle them, or let them propagate to whoever can decide what to do with them. What is the caller going to do if the request fails? What does that `true/false` result even mean? Authentication error? DNS error? Something else?

Comment: BTW streams also need closing. `sourceStream` and `responseStream` should be declared in `using` blocks too

Comment: That is a good idéa to use using that dispose them if an exception occurs. I tried to declare this but it doesn't seem to be correct?: `using (FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someurl.com/Folder1/test1.jpg"){ }`

Comment: That was a typo.

Comment: BTW you can eliminate the copying code and buffering the entire file by using `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)` or `Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream)`.

Comment: I think I am a little bit confused :) I should use closing for `sourceStream` `responseStream` and `FtpWebRequest` but are not sure how to set this up in my code. I am not sure if I need to wrap everything differently like nest everything up?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure which code that does the copying and how to replace it with `Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream)`

Comment: I think it is a little bit to difficult for me to change my code to using statements. I would be happy to see a code example of how that is done in my scenario with async/await also as I use.

Comment: Check the documentation example [How to: Upload files with FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the web request, response and stream objects are closed even if an exception occurs, they should be defined in a `using` block.

The code can be simplified to :

```
var ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
var imageExtensions=new[]{".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".gif",".bmp"};
var isimage = imageExtensions.Contains(ext);

var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someurl.com/Folder1/test1.jpg");

request.UseBinary =isimage;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.ConnectionGroupName = "Group1";
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 4;

//These are the credentials.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

using(var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
using(var requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
{
    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
}

using(var responseWeb = await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    var response = (FtpWebResponse)responseWeb;
    if (response.StatusDescription.Contains("226"))
    {
         return true;
    }
}
.....
```

I removed the [KeepAlive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.keepalive?view=netframework-4.8) and [UsePassive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive?view=netframework-4.8) setters because `true` is their default value.

A WebRequest by itself doesn't hold any resources so it doesn't implement IDisposable. The connection to the server is made when `GetRequestStream()` is called. The values that need disposing/closing are `sourceStream`, `requestStream` and `responseWeb`.

Comment: That is great, thank you for showing me how this is done!. I wonder I could see that `sourceStream` and `requestStream` is using the using stament. The `response` and `request`, I can't see in the code that they .Close() after they are used? Do I miss something there or should they not be closed?

Comment: That's what `using` is about. It calls `Dispose()` on those objects when execution exits the scope of the `using` block. `Dispose` in turn calls `Close()`. You can call `Close()` earlier if you want, but `using` ensures the streams and response will close no matter what

Comment: Yes I see, so `request` and `response` will `Close()` because they are involved in using statements? (I am a little bit bad when it comes to FTP, Signomi :))

Comment: I ment only ´response´ will `Close()` because it is inside a using statment.